# UITextView with DatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview, uidatepicker

I have an `UITextView` and one of my methods requires to change the `UITextView` inputView to an `UIDatePicker`, so the user can select a date for a reminder.

Here is the code I used

```
self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.noteTextView.inputView = self.datePicker;
[self.noteTextView becomeFirstResponder];
```

everything works perfectly, but I can't manage to switch back from datePicker to the default keyboard. What I have tried is the following code:

```
self.noteTextView.inputView = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
```

Comment: Is the UITextView noteTextView OR noteVite ?

Comment: @Nitish noteTextView, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the input view to nil

```
self.noteVite.inputView = nil;
```